# How to deploy multi instances with pserve via different port, but same server and diff dir?

Tags: pyramid

I want to deploy my `pyramid` app with `pserve` in same one server, but diff dir, production.ini and development.ini use different port:

release dir: release, started by `;pserve production.ini --reload`
dev dir:dev, started by `pserve development.ini --reload`

but any access in DEV, it's always routed to RELEASE code.
what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you're connecting to the correct port specified in each INI file.

Second, make sure you created separate virtualenvs for each version of the project and installed the code separately in each.

Third, make sure you understand the difference between editable mode and non-editable mode installs if you're expecting changes you made to show up. Generally you should just keep using editable mode even in production unless you know what you're doing. This means always doing `$VENV/bin/pip install -e .` from the source folder to install the code into the virtualenv.